# Unexpected merge error in a git svn system?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a somewhat convoluted setup (as in [git svn dcommit committing wrong file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041204/git-svn-dcommit-committing-wrong-file)) that looks something like this (produced in Dia, [testrepo.dia](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3a81678c99f14d557a4e/raw/testrepo.dia), posted in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a81678c99f14d557a4e)) - and is simulated with the script below, `testrepo.sh`:

[image: /tmp/testrepo.png]

Basically, I've had an SVN repository on a web server (`myrepo_svn_WS`), which at first I worked with through an SVN working copy on my local PC (`myrepo_svnco`). After a while, I stopped with that, and I moved to `git-svn`; but instead of using it directly from my local PC - I had set up a `myrepo_gitsvn` on my local server; from it a bare git repo is made on the local server, `myrepo_git_LS.git`, which is added as a remote origin of the `myrepo_gitsvn`. The idea is then that I can work from local PCs in respect to `myrepo_git_LS.git`, and keep the local network work in sync - even if the svn web server goes temporarily offline.

The below script, [`testrepo.sh`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3a81678c99f14d557a4e/raw/testrepo.sh), simulates this process locally - including the `myrepo_svn_WS` going offline. If you use the script as is, you'll notice that the system can "recover" from the SVN "WS" server going offline, and the log in that case is [testrepo_nofail.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3a81678c99f14d557a4e/raw/testrepo_nofail.log). However, if you uncomment the `#~` commented lines, which do a `git fetch origingit`, you will notice that the process fails, for which the log is [testrepo_fail.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3a81678c99f14d557a4e/raw/testrepo_fail.log):

```
remote: Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
remote: Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
remote: Auto-merging folder/file.txt
remote: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in folder/file.txt
remote: Failed to merge in the changes.
remote: Patch failed at 0001 5th git commit
remote: 
remote: When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
remote: If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
remote: To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

What confuses me here (and why I find this unexpected) - is that I am the *only* user here, and thus I don't even use branches at all! In that case, how could I possibly get a "merge conflict"?

The thing is - now the system has actually ended up in this failed state; so my question is: how can I recover the system back to proper working state, such that when I do a commit and push from the local `myrepo_git_wc`, the SVN web sever `myrepo_svn_WS` properly updates?

A few notes from comparing the logs with `meld`:

Note that right after the "Simulating merge conflict via git fetch" part, the process seems to go on properly - except that there is now a `origingit/master` branch (click for full size):

[image: testrepo_meld_01.png]

I didn't think much of this, because I didn't think of `git-svn` as a branch; but here is a subquestion: of `git-svn` and `origingit/master`, which one is a branch?

That part ends here:

[image: /testrepo_meld_02.png]

Notice that in the end, the non-failed process shows the log graph tree as "compacted" or "flattened" (i.e. no branches are sticking out) - while the failed process at that point doesn't complain of errors, but shows the log graph tree as branched.

The problem occurs only after the '6th git commit':

[image: testrepo_meld_03.png]

The failed process actually starts, for some reason 'Applying 5th git commit', which at that point should have already been handled; and at that point, the merge conflict occurs.

So, provided my system (or rather, `myrepo_gitsvn`) is in this failed state, what can I do to recover it?

Here is the `testrepo.sh` code:

```bash
set -x

rm -rf /tmp/myrepo*
cd /tmp

echo "simulating svn web server repo"

svnadmin create myrepo_svn_WS
# svn co file:///tmp/myrepo_svn_WS myrepo_svnco
read -s -p "Enter ssh pass [note, you will be prompted again via GUI for the same]: " SSHPASS
export SSHPASS
# note: the next command will again prompt for sshpass in GUI once, regardless of the SSHPASS variable
sshpass -e svn co svn+ssh://localhost/tmp/myrepo_svn_WS myrepo_svnco
cd /tmp/myrepo_svnco

echo "Adding first commits via svn"

echo aaa > AA.txt
svn add AA.txt
sshpass -e svn ci -m 'first svn commit'

echo bbb > BB.txt
svn add BB.txt
sshpass -e svn ci -m '2nd svn commit'

echo ccc > CC.txt
svn add CC.txt
sshpass -e svn ci -m '3rd svn commit'

echo ddd > DD.txt
svn add DD.txt
sshpass -e svn ci -m '4th svn commit'

echo eee > EE.txt
svn add EE.txt
sshpass -e svn ci -m '5th svn commit'

cd /tmp
echo "Cloning svn as git"

sshpass -e git svn clone svn+ssh://localhost/tmp/myrepo_svn_WS myrepo_gitsvn

echo "Cloning a bare git local server"

git clone --bare myrepo_gitsvn myrepo_git_LS.git

echo "Adding a git local server remote to the gitsvn"

cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn
git remote add origingit file:///tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git

cd /tmp
cat > /tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git/hooks/post-update <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export SSHPASS=${SSHPASS}
#export GIT_DIR="."
git update-server-info
export GIT_DIR=".git"
echo "post-update kicking in"
cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn
git pull --rebase origingit master
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date-order
sshpass -e git svn rebase
sshpass -e git svn dcommit
sshpass -e git svn rebase
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date-order
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git/hooks/post-update

cd /tmp
echo "Cloning a git local server to git local working copy"

sshpass -e git clone ssh://localhost/tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git myrepo_git_wc

cd /tmp/myrepo_git_wc
echo "Working from git local working copy now"
git config user.name me
git config user.email me@myself.com

mkdir folder
echo hhh > folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "1st git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo iiii >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "2nd git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo "Simulating svn server offline; git wc commits get added"
mv /tmp/myrepo_svn_WS /tmp/.myrepo_svn_WS

echo jjj >> folder/file.txt
echo jjj > folder/file2.txt
git add folder/file*.txt
git commit -m "3rd git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo kkkk >> folder/file.txt
echo kkkk >> folder/file2.txt
git add folder/file*.txt
git commit -m "4th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo "Simulating svn server back online; git wc commits get added"
mv /tmp/.myrepo_svn_WS /tmp/myrepo_svn_WS

#~ echo "Simulating merge conflict via git fetch"
#~ (cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn; git fetch origingit)

echo lll >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "5th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo mmm >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "6th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master
```

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855197/git-svn-rebase-is-failing-with-a-conflict-to-a-file-that-does-not-exist-in-git and https://github.com/abhikp/git-test/wiki/Getting-commits-from-SVN

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I got somewhere - but I'm really not sure if this will work for all edge cases, so an eventual more erudite answer will be appreciated.

First, a note: you can obtain the logs with `bash testrepo.sh 2>&1 | tee testrepo_MARK.log`; and you can [remove the control characters inserted by git remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-do-we-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell/29052115#29052115) from the logs with: `sed -i 's/\x1b\[\x4b//g' testrepo*.log`.

Anyways - apparently when doing `git fetch`, it adds a so-called local remote-tracking branch, which can be deleted as per [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/23961231#23961231) (to not add that "local remote-tracking branch", one should apparently call `git fetch <remote> --prune` instead). 
But that is not enough if doing a recovery from a broken state; the broken state apparently means there is a record of an unsuccessful merge, that should be removed (for which `git rebase --abort` can be used, as the program itself recommends). So in short, the fix would be:

```
cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn
git branch --delete --remotes origingit/master
git rebase --abort
```

Here is a modification of the above script, that will allow for simulating the break and the recovery (just replace the respective parts in the OP script):

```bash
# ...
cd /tmp
cat > /tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git/hooks/post-update <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export SSHPASS=${SSHPASS}
#export GIT_DIR="."
git update-server-info
export GIT_DIR=".git"
echo "post-update kicking in"
cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn
git svn info | grep Rev
git pull --rebase origingit master
git svn info | grep Rev
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date-order
sshpass -e git svn rebase
sshpass -e git svn dcommit
sshpass -e git svn rebase
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date-order
git svn info | grep Rev
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/myrepo_git_LS.git/hooks/post-update

# ...

echo "Simulating svn server back online; git wc commits get added"
mv /tmp/.myrepo_svn_WS /tmp/myrepo_svn_WS

DOCONFLICT=true
if [ "${DOCONFLICT}" = "true" ] ; then
echo "Simulating merge conflict via git fetch"
(cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn; git fetch origingit)
fi

echo lll >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "5th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo mmm >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "6th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

DOFIX=true
if [ "${DOCONFLICT}" = "true" ] ; then
if [ "${DOFIX}" = "true" ] ; then
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/23961231#23961231
  (cd /tmp/myrepo_gitsvn;
  git branch --delete --remotes origingit/master;
  git rebase --abort;
  )
fi
fi

echo nnn >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "7th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master

echo ooo >> folder/file.txt
git add folder/file.txt
git commit -m "8th git commit"
sshpass -e git push origin master
```

There are a few more commits, to test if the recovery holds; seemingly it does, because for the last commit, now this can be seen in the logs comparison:

[image: /tmp/testrepo_meld_04.png]

... so apart from a slight rearrangement, the log graph looks nearly the same. Also, note that as the added `git svn info` tells up, every time there is a "rewinding head to replay your work on top of it", git-svn actually brings the repository to commit 5 (which is the last one that was done solely in Subversion, before migrating to git-svn); not sure why this is. And at end, when the compacted log graph is shown after the final commit, all seems to look good:

[image: testrepo_meld_05.png]

Well, I hope this will help me get my actual repository fixed ...